# ASP .NET MVC call function on background, resize font without JS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I`m working on ASP .NET MVC 5 app which will be used with older people too. I have two questions:

1.: Is in ASP .NET some way to call controller method on background? This method cause some changes in CSS file. I have a button there and after click I need to call this method and refresh a site. The only problem is that I can`t use JavaScript - if JS is turned off in browser this function should still works.

2.: Is possible to implement functionality for simple increasing or decreasing of font size for whole page with storing this info in some session cookies - like we know it using JavaScript but as I said in previous question - it should work even if JS is turned off.

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: There is no reason why not to use JS in today's technology, most of the browser if not all are JS turned on by default.

Comment: You can do this in web forms. Have you considered using it ?

Comment: If you can't (won't) use JavaScript then everything will have to be done via page requests to server-side code.  There's no other universal in-browser language/platform available.  For doing this with server-side code, what have you tried?

Comment: There are some law rules - everything should be working even if JS is disabled. I´ve tried to call this method when user clicks on button, it calls method but not on background - return value (boolean) was shown in view.

Comment: You would have to consider using web forms as everything on the page should be server side controls which can be controlled directly from the server.

Comment: And is possible to combine MVC with WebForms?

Comment: If you have "return value" then you're using javascript

Comment: For 2 - Press: `control +` and `control -` or `pinch` for mobile - there's no need for you to code this, it's built-in

Comment: Many thanks for all your responces. I have another question - can ASP .NET MVC fully works without JS? I´m not talking about some special functionalities or some bootstrap included functions (menu, popups ...) but only using methods in controllers, views, models and entity framework. Can this work completely without JS?

Comment: You can build websites using `ASP.NET MVC` without JavaScript at all. It's not a requirement.

Comment: My team leader now told me, I can use JavaScript but with noscript tags including some information if JS is turned off.

Comment: You want to use [Progressive Enhancement (or Graceful Degradation)](https://www.google.com/search?q=Progressive+Enhancement+Graceful+Degradation).  So your website works *without* js in the *first instance*, then if they have js, they get nice stuff like ajax calls / dynamic css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One ASP.Net integrates WebForms, MVC and WebApi. I would suggest going down this route for your project as webforms can be used to make all of you page controls server controls which can be managed and manipulated from the server side. Take a look

http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/whats-new-in-visual-studio-2013/one-aspnet-integrating-aspnet-web-forms-mvc-and-web-api